# Pythonic way of injecting adapters that conform to a common interface

Tags: python

I'm setting up some routing for AWS using boto3.

In AWS environments, we want to have a class that's responsible for poking the route into the EC2 VPC. In non-AWS environments, it'll do something else.

In the traditional OOP approach I would have an interface that defines an `announce_route` method, for example, and create concrete instances of AWSRouting or FoobarRouting, etc.

Pseudocode to illustrate the scenario:

```
interface Routing
   function announceRoute()

class AWSRouting implements Routing

class RouteAnnouncer
   function constructor(Routing routing)
```

I would inject the appropriate instance of Routing into the announcer depending on some environment variable or config option.

What would be the pythonic way of achieving this kind of adapter pattern with dependency injection? So far I've not seen any way of defining the type for a dependency to a constructor or setter.

---

This is what I've got so far:

```
class RouteAnnouncer:
    def __init__(self, adapter):
        self.adapter = adapter

    def announce_route(self, ip_addr):
        self.adapter.announce_route(ip_addr)


class AnnounceRouteContract:
    def announce_route(self, ip_addr):
        raise NotImplementedError


class AWSRouting(AnnounceRouteContract):
    def announce_route(self, ip_addr):
        pass


class StandardRouting(AnnounceRouteContract):
    def announce_route(self, ip_addr):
        pass
```

So I think what I'm really missing there is how to tell users of the code that the adapter in the `RouteAnnouncer` is an instance of `AnnounceRouteContract`.

Comment: did you have a look at [dependency injection - the python way](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/413268/)?

Comment: Almost every time you think that you need to provide the type of the class you're wrong. Embrace the duck typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything nearly so silly as creating a bunch of "interfaces". In Python your interface is determined by how you behave. Commonly called "Duck Typing", because if you look like a duck, you walk like a duck, and you quack like a duck, well then you must be a duck.

We don't care if you're *really* a person in a duck costume, or a cardboard cutout of a duck, or a robot duck. That's entirely irrelevant.

It looks like all that you *really* care about in your case is that `announce_route(ip_addr)` is something that you can call. Of course ultimately you hope that it's going to actually set up the routes, but you know, that's what testing is for.

What you *may* want to do is have a factory that looks something like this:

```
class MyRouteAnnouncer:
    def __init__(self):
        ...  # whatever you need to do

    def announce_route(self, ip_addr):
        ...  # do what you need to do


def get_router():
    if env.is_aws():
        return boto3
    elif env.is_something_else():
        return MyRouteAnnouncer()
    else:
        raise Exception('Unknown environment')
```

And then whatever calls the `get_router()` function just gets the appropriate router and calls `announce_route(ip_addr)` on it.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is why I'm asking - I know my previous way of thinking probably doesn't/shouldn't apply to python so was looking for the approach I should be taking instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can't force class users to put only instance of specific class by native python(In python 3.6 seem it is implemented). You can just give a hint for users so IDE can complain if there is an instance of not expected class:

```
class RouteAnnouncer:
    def __init__(self, adapter):
        """
        :param AnnounceRouteContract adapter: Route adapter
        self.adapter = adapter
```

Also make contract Abstract as well as `announce_route` method to force users implement it.

Also you can use [issubclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass) built-in function to check whether adapter is instance of expected contract

Answer (score 1):

In python world, there is no way to specify parameter types. I think one appropriate way is using assertion to check adapter type in function internal.

```
class RouteAnnouncer:
    def __init__(self, adapter):
        assert isinstance(adapter, AnnounceRouteContract)
        self.adapter = adapter
```